# Rails 3: How to simply test pessimistic locking on console

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, pessimistic-locking

I'm currently doing a pessimistic loking with rails 3 + postgresql. But there seems to be no way to confirm that the lock is working unless I go through the hassle of making a concurrent test. Is there no way to test this via console?

Example

```
User.transaction do 
  u1 = User.find(1, :lock => true)
  u2 = User.find(1)
  ## u2 should not be able to do anything right?
end
```

Answer (score 8):

Open 2 consoles

Console 1:

```
User.transaction do 
  u = User.find(1, :lock => true)
  sleep(30)
end
```

Once that is executed switch to console 2 then do this

Console 2:

```
u = User.find(1)
u.name = "new name"
u.save!
```

You will then see that console 2 will not commit it's update not until the 30 second sleep on console 1 is finished.